# Fastest method to read from stdin in python, for competitive programming?

Tags: python

A few days ago I stumbled with a problem in competitive programming which has never been solved in Python. It's because that problem has a too big input and Python seems to be very slow in reading from stdin (standard input). The input consists of a sequence of integers separated by just one character, which will be either a space (" ") or a line break ("\n").

The fastest input reading code I was able to create is the one below. It reads the entire binary input at once, then joins those sets of bytes to form integers. And it provides the result through an input iterator (using the `yield` clause). Knowing that the digits 0-9 have ASCII code of 48-57 and the integer separators use characters below this range, all it needs to check is if the byte is >= 48.

```py
from os import read
from os import fstat

def createInputIterator():
    vs = 0
    for v in read(0, fstat(0).st_size):
        if v >= 48:
            vs *= 10
            vs += v - 48
        else:
            yield vs # another complete integer has been read
            vs = 0

iterator = createInputIterator()

# numbers are consumed one by one like this:
# for i in range( ... ):
x = next(iterator)
```

Is it possible to make this code any faster?

PS: The code I have just needs 5% of performance improvement to finish the task within the expected time frame of 2s and I have measured the input reading part as being the bottleneck (it's consuming more than 50% of the execution time).

Comment: Python is the most common language used in coding challenges. Many challenges are practically designed around it. There are a lot of things slow about Python, but the *input buffering* is not the bottleneck. I can almost guarantee that, whatever happened at your competitive programming challenge, your bottleneck was somewhere else in your algorithm. Reading input is an *IO-bound* task, which means that the Python part is just a thin shell wrapper around the actual operating system calls which run in, let's be honest, probably C. Python barely even has a say in the matter.

Comment: I get the feeling `for i in map(int, sys.stdin.read().split()): ...` would do a lot better than this.

Comment: SO is not for code reviews. Delete this and ask, instead, on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Rob: Stack Overflow is perfectly capable of handling "my code isn't fast enough, please help" sort of questions. Code Review is for making working code less *ugly*, but this code, for the OP's purposes, does not work.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The code works. The question is, "Is it possible to make this code any faster?" Which is opinion anyway but performance questions are under the purview of Code Review

Comment: @Rob: Which is a perfectly legitimate question for StackOverflow... It's in the gap between the two sites where it's fine for either, not restricted to one or the other. And fastest code is definitely not *opinion-based*; you can quantify performance (even if my particular laptop is pretty terrible at that).

Comment: @SilvioMayolo That's hardly true. Most competitive programming problems have time limits based on C or C++ solutions; for some of them, even Java requires extreme I/O optimization to pass with the **same** algorithm, not to mention Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the simpler: `for i in map(int, itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(bytes.split, sys.stdin.buffer))):` (or `for i in map(int, sys.stdin.buffer.read().split())`, which delays beginning work, but can be faster by doing more work in bulk)? That'll still bypass decoding to text (the `int` constructor is perfectly happy to convert from `bytes` representing ASCII directly, so this is *probably* faster than the otherwise equivalent `for i in map(int, itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, sys.stdin))):`), it'll start giving you results immediately (rather than needing to bulk read the whole file up front before you can do anything), the OS will be able to start prebuffering data in the file while you're using what you've read so far, and it avoids the wastefulness/unPythonicness of `for i in range(n):` when you're using that to do something `n` number of times (in this case, `next(mygenerator)`); direct iteration without manually calling `next` over and over saves a lot of pointless overhead.

I haven't tested it, largely because I'm on a laptop that doesn't give repeatable timings right now, but I'm somewhat skeptical that the extreme amount of simple math your solution requires will work all that efficiently in the CPython reference interpreter (which is historically pretty terrible at simple math, on an overhead:useful-work level, though as of 3.12 it's made some significant strides there).

Comment: Thanks. Both of your suggestions work, made the code simpler and a small increase in performance, but no enough to avoid the timeout. The number processing is simple. I found many ways to solve and one of them in O(n). But the input seems to have millions of numbers. This is why I could measure it as the bottleneck.

Comment: @MuriloPerrone: There's not a lot to be improved here unfortunately. `numpy` loading *might* help (I don't use it enough to know for sure), but many of these challenges don't let you use it. If you're close to the threshold, optimizing the non-input-related aspects may be necessary (either by going below `O(n)`, or by finding better `O(n)` solutions), but you haven't given us any clue as to what you're doing there.